# Emacs EIN display file name without path

Tags: emacs

I'm very new to emacs and know next to nothing.
I would like to better use EIN but one thing which bugs me is that whenever I open a notebook, the modeline displays the entire path to the file which I've opened, followed by the filename.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epid4.png)

This is way too long so as to make EIN very difficult to use, especially if the frame is split into 2 windows. I've tried setting all sorts of things in my init.el with the assistance of chatGPT but none of it works. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I've tried setting all sorts of things in my init.el with the assistance of chatGPT but none of it works.

Comment: I don't think that's what you'll see if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). If it is then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If it's not what you see then bisect your init file to find where you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Hi Drew, since 'emacs -Q' start with no init, shouldn't the default behavior of emacs be that it finds no installed packages? I ask because this is exactly what I'm getting, I've no access to 'ein' or anything when starting with 'emacs -Q'...

Having said that my init file is quite sparse since I'm a beginner  with emacs so I would be surprised that the problem came from that. Of course I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [doom-modeline](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline) package which will automatically shorten the path.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've just installed doom-modeline but unfortunately that made no difference...

Comment: You can try this opinion `(setq doom-modeline-buffer-file-name-style 'file-name)`.

Comment: Hi, I tried (setq doom-modeline-buffer-file-name-style 'file-name) but that made no changes unfortunately. Thank you for the suggestions nevertheless.